# Detect MouseEnter event while mouse is pressed

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, drag-and-drop, mouseenter

Is it possible to detect if the mouse enters a `Control` while the mouse is pressed?

I assume that the traditional `MouseEnter event` is not firing if the mouse is pressed because there are some conflicts with the `DragAndDrop` functionality?

Setting `.Capture = false` is not appropriate in this case, because during the `MouseDown` the `MouseMove` event has to be captured/handled

Comment: Drag and drop has its own DragEnter, DragOver and DragDrop events.  But I dont think it fires if it is down when it enters.

Answer (score 3):

Well, yes, this is technically possible.  Not something you should ever do however.

What matters is where the mouse cursor was at when you pressed the mouse button.  This fires the MouseDown event on the underlying control.  But does something else, it also captures the mouse.  Exposed by the Control.Capture property.

This is important, it ensures that the MouseUp event will be reliably fired.  Many controls use that event to fire the Click event.  Like a Button.  A side-effect is that the control you move the mouse to while holding down the button will not see any mouse messages.  They go the clicked control instead.  Even if you move the mouse completely outside of the control.

This can be tinkered with.  You could, say, set the Capture property back to *false* in the control's MouseDown event handler, in effect making the click entirely ineffective.  Or you could monitor the mouse position with MouseMove and cancel the capture when you see it move outside of the DisplayRectangle.

Things you can do, but you probably shouldn't.  You make your UI behave differently from the UI of most any other program the user is familiar with.  Or worse, it is inconsistent in your own UI, pretty likely to happen.  Confusing the user like this is very rarely a good idea.  It is up to you.

Comment: *... it ensures that the MouseUp event will be reliably fired*. No. The *mouseup* event doesn't always fire. The mouseleave and capturechanged are always fired.

Comment: That is not untrue, Ctrl+Escape is a boss override.  I don't think incorporating that is going to make the answer easier to understand though :)  Exception noted.

Answer (score 0):

First i would like to thank @Hans for his answer. It is very informative and well structured +1!

But in my case, this answer was not a valid solution. Setting `.Capture = False` within the `MouseDown` event has too many disadvantages.

**I solved the problem by passing the `Controls` which should react on the `MouseEnter` event to a `List(Of)` in the `Control`, which fires the `MouseDown` and `MouseMove` events.**

Within the `MouseMove` handle it is checked if the mouse position is inside one of the `List(Of)-Controls` If the mouse is within the bounds of one of these `Controls`, the `OnMouseEnter(ByVal e as System.EventArgs)` is called explicitly.